# mysql select where base64 not before

Tags: mysql, base64

How do I `Select` a query from mysql and search `WHERE` it from a column that is based64 encoded?

any kind of help is great appreciated:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE base64_decode(name) LIKE '%bobby%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL 5.6.1 you can do this with [FROM_BASE64()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64).

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE FROM_BASE64(name) LIKE '%bobby%'
```

Earlier versions require a UDF to be installed.

But the question is: why are you encoding data you later want to search on?